# Phonegap upload photos to a website

Tags: android, cordova, image-uploading

Hello I am developing an app with phonegap using android and I want to let users take a photo then upload it.  I understand well enough what to do on the phonegap side but what do I need to do on the website side?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a couple of good articles.

[Upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap](http://zacvineyard.com/blog/2011/03/upload-a-file-to-a-remote-server-with-phonegap)

[Upload a picture using phonegap on android](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mydeveloperworks/blogs/94e7fded-7162-445e-8ceb-97a2140866a9/entry/upload_a_picture_using_phonegap_on_android8?lang=en)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what kind of language you want to use, but you should check out this thread:

[Upload Photo from iPhone to PHP Using PhoneGap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5286744/upload-photo-from-iphone-to-php-using-phonegap)